# How to keep pdf structure after add/replace image by Aspose.Pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose.pdf

I trying to replace images in a pdf page with another image outside using Aspose.Pdf. This is the pdf before replace that's opened by AI:
[image]

And this is the pdf after replace:
[image]

How can I keep the structure of pdf when I do replacement?

Thanks.

Comment: The Aspose evaluation Version adds an evaluation Banner. Thus, obviously there are structural changes. ..

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be due to the evaluation version you are using. The evaluation watermark is added to the PDF file and that is causing the structure to change. I would suggest you to request a temporary license file using this [link](http://goo.gl/YVMGOz). Try with the temporary license and check the structure of the generated file.

P.S. I am working as Social Media Developer at Aspose.